# Error al cargar al servidor un archivo .CSV (failed to open stream: Permission denied)

Tags: php, csv, servidor

Estoy en PHP. No se cual es el motivo de este error. Estoy intentando cargar un archivo `csv` al servidor pero llega este error:

> nombre_del_archivo.csv Warning: copy(nombre_del_archivo.csv): failed
> to open stream: Permission denied in /ruta donde esta el archivo
> php/importar_masivos.php on line 27

```
<?php 
include('../clases/clases.php');

$instance = new conectar();
$cerasesion  = new crearSesion();

if (isset($_POST["enviar"])){ //isset permite recepcionar una variable que si exista y que no sea null (vacia) 
    function insertar_datos($nombre, $apellido){
        $instance->traerdatos("INSERT INTO PRUBLANCO.PRUEBA (NOMBRE, APELLIDO) VALUES ('$nombre', '$apellido')"); 
    } 
        
    if ($instance = true) {
        echo "instance ejecutada <br/>";
    }else{
        echo "no se insertaron datos <br/>";
    }

    $archivo = $_FILES["archivo"]["name"]; // _FILES contendrá toda la información de los los ficheros subidos
    $archivo_copiado = $_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"];
    $archivo_guardado =  $archivo; 

    if (copy($archivo_copiado , $archivo_guardado)) {   //linea 27 donde genera el error
        if (file_exists($archivo_guardado)) { // "file_exists"Comprueba si existe un fichero o directorio
            $fp = fopen($archivo_guardado, "r" ); // "fopen" abrir un archivo (abre un fichero)
            while ($datos = fgetcsv($fp , 0 , ";" )) {  // "fgetcsv" Obtiene una línea de un puntero a un fichero y la analiza en busca de campos CSV
                $resultado = insertar_datos($datos[0], $datos[1]);
            }
            if ($resultado = true) {
                echo 'Se insertaron los datos correctamente a la base de datos <br/>';
            } else {
                echo "Error de formato";
            }
        } else {
            echo "no existe un archivo <br/>";
        }
    }         
}

?>
```

Comment: Buen día, ya checaste permisos de escritura en la ruta que señalas ?

Comment: Dos cosas básicas:  1) Las comparaciones se hacen con doble símbolo del `=`, es decir, así:  `if ($instance == true)` y así: `if ($resultado == true) {`. En el otro caso siempre es true, pues tan solo lo asignas, no lo comparas.  y 2) Aprende a usar esta función [move_uploaded_file()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.move-uploaded-file.php) en lugar de intentarlo con `copy()`. Mírate bien los ejemplos y sobretodo repasa bien la ruta donde lo vas a poner, pues en tu pregunta intentas ponerlo en la raiz de tu web, y quizas alli no puedes. Create una subcarpeta con permisos mejor.

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta, si eran permisos de escritura en la ruta